# How can i convert a JSON file in R to a dataframe?

Tags: r, json

I want to load the data from a JSON file into R to make a new dataframe. However the JSON file consists out of other links with data, so i can't seem to find the actual data from the JSON file. I got the JSON file from this website: https://ckan.dataplatform.nl/dataset/467dc230-20e0-4c3a-8240-dccbfc20807a/resource/531cc276-b88e-49bb-a97f-443707936a12/download/p-route-autoparkeren.json

This is the code i used.

```
library(rjson)
JSONList1 <- fromJSON(file = "utrecht2.json")
print(JSONList1)
JSONList1_df <- as.data.frame(JSONList1)
```

when i use this code i get only 1 observation with 411 variables.
Any idea how to do this? I'm a beginner and i've never worked with JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `fromJSON` from package `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
JSONList1 <- fromJSON("https://ckan.dataplatform.nl/dataset/467dc230-20e0-4c3a-8240-dccbfc20807a/resource/531cc276-b88e-49bb-a97f-443707936a12/download/p-route-autoparkeren.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several packages offering JSON importing abilities. If I use the one I am involved with, then *the resulting data appears to contain a data.frame as the first list element*.

```
d <- RcppSimdJson::fload("https://ckan.dataplatform.nl/dataset/467dc230-20e0-4c3a-8240-dccbfc20807a/resource/531cc276-b88e-49bb-a97f-443707936a12/download/p-route-autoparkeren.json")
> class(d)
[1] "list"
> class(d[[1]])
[1] "data.frame"
>
> head(d[[1]])
                                                                                        dynamicDataUrl
1 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/dynamic/8d85bbdb-8bbd-4a24-b35f-85f21186ec04
2 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/dynamic/21b0388a-56f7-4cba-8fd3-4a1c914f5fe2
3 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/dynamic/45434989-3252-4c85-8731-c856b02c390c
4 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/dynamic/9064b206-7e62-402d-ae62-f25a0e47571b
5 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/dynamic/5829fb06-ee4a-4762-946c-ed6209edf7d5
6 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/dynamic/e4da517a-ef32-426d-821c-96e29ac5ac80
                                                                                        staticDataUrl
1 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/static/8d85bbdb-8bbd-4a24-b35f-85f21186ec04
2 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/static/21b0388a-56f7-4cba-8fd3-4a1c914f5fe2
3 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/static/45434989-3252-4c85-8731-c856b02c390c
4 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/static/9064b206-7e62-402d-ae62-f25a0e47571b
5 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/static/5829fb06-ee4a-4762-946c-ed6209edf7d5
6 http://opendata.technolution.nl/opendata/parkingdata/v1/static/e4da517a-ef32-426d-821c-96e29ac5ac80
  limitedAccess                           identifier                        name
1         FALSE 8d85bbdb-8bbd-4a24-b35f-85f21186ec04           P06 - Sluisstraat
2         FALSE 21b0388a-56f7-4cba-8fd3-4a1c914f5fe2                  3 - Burcht
3         FALSE 45434989-3252-4c85-8731-c856b02c390c         P01 - Stationsplein
4         FALSE 9064b206-7e62-402d-ae62-f25a0e47571b Jaarbeurs P3 - Jaarbeurs P3
5         FALSE 5829fb06-ee4a-4762-946c-ed6209edf7d5        P03 - Dek Stadspoort
6         FALSE e4da517a-ef32-426d-821c-96e29ac5ac80       PG-Pieter Vreedeplein
                         locationForDisplay
1                                        NA
2 WGS84, 52.4387428557465, 4.82805132865906
3 WGS84, 52.2573226613971, 6.16240739822388
4 WGS84, 52.0854991774024, 5.10619640350342
5  WGS84, 52.256324421386, 6.15569114685059
6 WGS84, 51.5582297848141, 5.08894979953766
>
```

I would expect this to be similar for the other ones.